# How do i replace an array with an arraylist?

Tags: java

How do I replace the following array with an ArrayList.

```
Employee[] companyTeam = {manager, engineer1, superviso1, accountant, intern };
```

Comment: Arrays.asList() will help..

Comment: If you really need a `java.util.ArrayList` check the duplicate question (above). FYI, `Arrays.asList` *really* returns an `Arrays.ArrayList`, although that might not matter.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like

```
List<Employee> companyTeam = Arrays.asList(manager, engineer1, superviso1, accountant, intern);
```

Comment: Arrays.asList(companyTeam) in case you already have an array..

Comment: the word "Arrays" and "List" is highlighted in red. Any idea why?

Comment: You need to import them. Add `import java.util.List;` and `import java.util.Arrays;` to the top of your file. Or if you're using Eclipse `ctrl + shift + O` will import them for you.

Comment: Hi Mike, that works. Thanks. But if Im only to use the import java.util.ArrayList command. How would I go about writing the code for it? I tried using
 ArrayList<Employee> companyTeam = {manager, engineer1, superviso1, accountant, intern};but then im getting an "illegal initializer for for ArrayList error"

Comment: You can do `ArrayList<Employee> companyTeam = new ArrayList<Employee>(Arrays.asList(manager, engineer1, superviso1, accountant, intern));`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Employee[] companyTeam = {manager, engineer1, superviso1, accountant, intern };
 List<Employee>  list=Arrays.asList(companyTeam);// array to List
```

You already have an array, So you can use `Arrays.asList(companyTeam)` to convert array to `List`